Problem importing itertools saying itertools not defined
Thank you to all who helped me with this question. I didn't post my entire code because I figured the line "import itertools" was implied and that the other lines did not pertain to the issue at hand. I found out that in the IDE I'm using, there is actually a button to search and download certain packages. Without doing that first it doesn't import any package. Then there was the secondary question embedded here. Namely, how to produce all 3 word combinations without repetition. That problem was also solved by user19077881. Thank you very much. I don't quite understand the proper etiquette here yet. I'm at the very early stages of learning. So I appreciate all of your feedback Anerdw.
I'm trying to build an algorithm that will return all possible 3 word combinations of an existing list with 278 words in it. But I've hit a wall.
for i in range(1, len(lst)+1):
    words.append(i)
    els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]
    words.append(els)

When I run it, it keeps telling me itertools is not defined.

UPDATE: I figured out the problem with importing itertools. However, as I guessed, the algorithm returns a list of every possible combination period. Can anybody help me get only 3-word combinations please?

Don't just comment, [edit] the question to reflect your actual problem. In what you've posted, it's not clear why you thought itertools would be defined.

That's one of the arguments of https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations just set it

"Problem importing itertools" - Your code isn't even trying to import it. What are you talking about?

@CavitTurnali If you solved this problem but have another one, you should ask a new question instead of posting a comment.

What's that super weird IDE you use where you need to download itertools and where you get a "not defined" error for the code you showed instead of a ModuleNotFoundError for the import itertools?

Using itertools.combinations you should specify the combinations sizing (3 in your case). To use a simple example:
import itertools

s = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

result = list(itertools.combinations(s, 3))

print(result)

gives a List of Tuples with each combination:
[('one', 'two', 'three'), ('one', 'two', 'four'), ('one', 'two', 'five'), ('one', 'three', 'four'), ('one', 'three', 'five'), ('one', 'four', 'five'), ('two', 'three', 'four'), ('two', 'three', 'five'), ('two', 'four', 'five'), ('three', 'four', 'five')]

or you can iterate to get each one in turn:
result = itertools.combinations(s, 3)

for combi in result:
    print(combi)


I don't think this answers the question. The question was about "itertools is not defined." This answer addresses a different problem.

@Anderdw import itertools resolves the not defined issue; the rest of the code answers the supplementary question. There is not much more can be said to meet the OP requirements.

Originally, I was having trouble importing itertools, but I figured it out. Thank you for answering the secondary question also user 19077881.
